# Problema instalando sqlsrv en php wampserver

Tags: php, sql-server, php7, wampserver

tengo un problema. estoy intentando instalar SQLSRV en WAMPSERVER (PHP 7.2.25), tengo los dll, modifico el `php.ini`, reinicio los servicios, me aparecen activos en las extensiones de php, pero cuando veo el `phpinfo()` no me aparece esta extension.

[image: wampserver]

[image: sqlsrv]

Tienen idea de que puede estar pasando?

Comment: ¿Qué pusiste en tu `php.ini` exactamente? Pulsa en [edit] para mostrarlo y verifica que la línea no sea sobre-escrita en el mismo `php.ini`

Comment: @A.Cedano ahí agregué mi contenido en el php.ini. puse el nombre del archivo luego del php_ y sin la extension.

Comment: [Según la doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/connect/php/loading-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-ver15), en Windows tienes que ponerle la extensión: `extension=php_sqlsrv_72_ts.dll`

Comment: Gracias!! @A.Cedano funciono eso!